# Issues manipulating a 2d Array

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

I have to take the variables stored in a 1d array, and put them into a 2d array using a for loop. I then need to initialize the rows 0 - 9 of the 2d array to the elements form the 1d array all of this will be done in a function. My questions are as follows.

1. Is it possible for me to more effiecently store the variables from the array gamma into the array inStock?
2. How can I initialize all of the rows to look like this, if it's even possible.

11

13

15

17

11

13

15

17

11

13

Once rows 0 - 9 have been initialized I need to then go over the remaining elements in the array and initialize them to the third power of the previous element

Example:

11 ^ 3  = 1331 , 1331 ^ 3 = 2357947691 and so on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int COLUMNS = 4;
const int ROWS = 10;

void copyGama(int tempGamma[], int gamma_size, int tempArray2[][COLUMNS]);

int main()
{
  int gamma[4] = { 11, 13, 15, 17 },
      inStock[ROWS][COLUMNS], 
      Gamma_Size = 4;

      void copyGama(gamma, Gamma_Size, inStock);

  for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
      {
        cout << setw(15) << inStock[i][j];
      }
    cout << "\n";
  }





return 0;
} 


void copyGama(int tempGamma[], int gamma_size, int tempArray2[][COLUMNS])
{
    int copyArray[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < gamma_size; i++)
    {   
       copyArray[i] = tempGamma[i]; 
       /* This loops coppies all elements in tempGamma[] and puts them 
          in copyArray[]
       */
    }


       for (int i = 0; i < ROWS - 5 ; i++)
       {    
            for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS - 3; j++)
            {
               tempArray2[i][j] = copyArray[i]; 

               /* This loop is where inStock[][] is initialized  
               */ 

            }
       }



            for (int i = 4; i < ROWS; i++)
            {
               for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
               {
                  tempArray2[i][j] = static_cast<double>(pow(tempArray2[i][j], 3)); 
                  /*  
                    This is where I attempt to initialize the remaining 
                    elements to the third power of the previous element
                  */
               }
            }



}
```

When the above code if run the output looks like this

```
         11     -858993460     -858993460     -858993460
         13     -858993460     -858993460     -858993460
         15     -858993460     -858993460     -858993460
         17     -858993460     -858993460     -858993460
-2147483648    -2147483648    -2147483648    -2147483648
-2147483648    -2147483648    -2147483648    -2147483648
-2147483648    -2147483648    -2147483648    -2147483648
-2147483648    -2147483648    -2147483648    -2147483648
-2147483648    -2147483648    -2147483648    -2147483648
-2147483648    -2147483648    -2147483648    -2147483648
```

I understand why the columns across to the right of the first four rows look the way do, an it's because they're being skipped each loop which I also need to fix.

What I really don't get is how I can initialize rows 0 - 9 because even if I remove  - 5 or -3 respectively it still doesn't work

EDIT: Cleaned up a few errors from copy pasting

EDIT: Added comments in loops to be clear about what they're for

Comment: You should step through your program line by line using the debugger to narrow the source of your error.

Comment: I get no errors when I compile, if you mean the logical error I already know where it is I'm just unsure as to how to fix it.

Comment: This will not compile: `int(main)`, it should be `int main(){...}`

Comment: Sorry... that was a typo..

Comment: And I fixed that :) didn't even notice it lol, I did this in vs 2015 so I re-wrote main lol my apologies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source has 4 elements, while destination has more than 4 elements. You can use the `%` mod operator to rotate between elements of the source:

```
//Pseudo code:
dst[0]=src[0];
dst[1]=src[1];
dst[2]=src[2];
dst[3]=src[3];
dst[4]=src[0];
dst[5]=src[1];
...
```

For example

```
void copyGama(int tempGamma[], int gamma_size, int tempArray2[][COLUMNS])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            int c = i % gamma_size;
            tempArray2[i][j] = tempGamma[c];
        }
    }

    /* un-comment this section later
    for (int i = 4; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            tempArray2[i][j] = static_cast<double>(pow(tempArray2[i][j], 3));
        }
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: Oh wow that cuts out a ton of waste, I didn't even think to use mod in this situation but it makes complete sense thank you so much!